# Get notification warning certificate when using Chrome on Android with Nodejs (expressjs) run on port 443 (https)

Tags: android, node.js

I have a problem with Expressjs - Nodejs with Https on Chrome of Android.

- My VPS runs both Apache and Nodejs
  First time, My team set up ssl for Apache and all device worked fine - that time Nodejs ran with port 3000. Because of some reason I used this SSL of apache for nodejs server and turn off it for apache (right now apache run on port 80)
- I use this code for getting CA. It works for almost browser and IOS (Safari) too, but it can not run on Chrome of Android and right now it alway show warning message about my certificate and prevent https (with the red line) run on nodejs service although user can go page normally
  **This is my code to get CA from apache:**
  Server side:

```js
var app   = express(),
    options  = {
       key : fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/thedragoncode.key').toString(),
       cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/thedragoncode.crt').toString(),
       requestCert: true,
       rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    https  = require('https').createServer(options, app);

    ...


     // This request use for mobile Android device
     app.get("/android/", function (req, res, next)
     {
        res.end("android development");
     });

     https.listen(443);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem this problem no one was got. I already resolved this problem by doing this way: http://www.benjiegillam.com/2012/06/node-dot-js-ssl-certificate-chain/

you just convert coffe script to javascript and it works fine to me. by fetch CA chain to array